# What is the precise differece between sharing vs following a document in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-365, onedrive-for-business, following

I just tried sharing a document with a fellow worker on skydrive pro and when the email is sent out, he sees only a link to the file and a link to "Follow".

Although he does get access to the shared resource, it however shows up under "Followed Documents" rather than showing up under "Shared with me". Refer Screenshot

This is probably a silly question but is there a different procedure to follow to get it under the latter?

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i'm correct, but when you are sharing a document you give access to the person you are sharing it with.

But if the user has access to the document and the library it will not show as they can find it themselves.. I only have a testsite with one user, so I could not test if it was correct.

Comment: Apparently you could have edit access to a document you are following and yet have it not show up under Shared with me

Comment: Is this also the case if the document is placed in a document library the user doesn't have access to? As John writes - shared documents from your mydocuments will show in the shared with me.. and you  don't have access to another persons mydocuments by default.

Answer (score 1):

Followed documents are items that you have chosen to follow by selecting the Follow button when viewing or selecting the document.

Shared with me documents are documents that other users have chosen to share with you.  For instance, from their own SkyDrive site, if they select a document in the My Documents section, and then select Share.

Comment: Thanks John!
The "Select share" button is exactly what I used, however the email notify thats fired as a result only has a follow link which in turn displays the shared resource under followed rather than Shared with me.